# Programming exercise is following: exercise on for-structure. How to write a program, which prints below christmastree?

Tags: java

```
                                   O
                                  OOO
                                 OOOOO
                                OOOOOOO
                               OOOOOOOOO
                              OOOOOOOOOOO
                             OOOOOOOOOOOOO
                            OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                           OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                          OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                         OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                        OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
                                   O
```

Is there some hint for me. I'm stuck. This should be possible to do with for-structure.

```
_ ~ empty 
0 ~ 0-sign
if luku =3 then.
__0__
_000_
00000
```

So

```
 for( int i=0; i<luku; i++)
    for( int j=0; j<luku; j++) 
       System.out.print(" ");
```

Comment: Don't close it. It's homework so treat it as such.

Comment: Its probably a nested (2 loops) for-structure.  One across and one down.

Comment: I would start with a program that prints an empty screen, and then extend it till finished ^-^

Comment: Without showing any of work at all or fruits of your current efforts or thoughts, there's little to suggest.

Comment: Here is a solution. I suggest not to just copy and paste, try to understand it. http://ideone.com/zlm6V

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hint:

```
int i, length = 20;       //adjust for your needs
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
    //print a space for (20-i)/2 times 
    //print '0' for i times
    //print a newline
}
```

I think this should get you started

Answer (score 3):

**Hints :**

Looping. You can solve this with two loops.

First will have as limit the number of lines.

Second loop will have a limit of one and will increase by two for each iteration. This until the second to last line.

Then you should print a single `0`.

There are plenty of ways to do this. While/for loops. `%` operator. Try something and come back for more help if you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You need a number of lines, and on every line there is an increasing number of 0s and a decreasing number of spaces. You create a for-loop, which usually increases a variable up to a certain point and then stops looping.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // print line
}
```

I think this is already too much help, but oh well. If you can't figure it out now, you should ask your teacher or read the book or look up "for-loops".

EDIT: maybe this solution in Brainfuck helps:

```
+++++
>>>>>>
++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++
>
++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++
>
++++++++++
<<<<<<<<
[->+>>>+<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<
>
[
>>[-]>>[-]+
<<<<<
[->>>+>+<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<<
>>
[->->+>++<<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<<
>>>
[->>>.<<<]
>>
[->>.<<]
>>>.
<<<<<<+<-
]
<
[->>>>>>.<<<<<<]>>>>>>>.>.
```

Try it, it works: http://koti.mbnet.fi/villes/php/bf.php
The number of '+' signs on the first line is the number of lines you need.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not the for loop but how to print an increasing number of 0es in a way to form a christmas tree.

Comment: That shoudn't be too hard, right? Or do I have high standards?

Comment: Well, no. But a simple for loop isn't that hard either.

Comment: +1 for showing a solution that uses a turing tarpit language. -1/2 for use of the term "moron".

Answer (score 2):

You can start with something like this. Which loops through the rows, and increases the number of innerloops to get more O's

```
for (int pos = 1; pos < 12; pos++) (
    for(int o = 0 ; o < p ; o++)
    {
        // Draw O
    }
}
```

Where you use p, which is increased each round, as the number of O's you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the program has the same start and end point, that is we display a single `O`
The first thing that must be done is to create a function that can print one `O` and from there it is easy to implement something that can print N `O`'s.  Pseudocode to follow:

```
function generateOh()  
{  
   return "O";  
}
```

So to print a tree we need a loop like so:

```
function generateTree(numberOfLevels, ohsToAddPerLevel)  
{  
   treeOutput = generateOh()  //Start
    ohsThisLevel = 1
    while i < numberOfLevels 
                 treeOutput += \n //don't forget the new line 
                 ohsThisLevel+= ohsToAddPerLevel  
                 for j < ohsThisLevel   
                     treeOutput +=  generateOh()    
                 i++
    treeOutput += \n
    treeOutput += generateOh() //End

}
```

The above code will produce output like follows:

```
O
OOO
OOOOO
OOOOOOO
O
```

The remainder is for you to center it appropriately.